# Modifying the user object with hook_user_load()

Tags: drupal

In Drupal 6 you could use code similar to the following one:

```
function example_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  switch($op) {
    case 'load':
      $account->fb_id ='xyz'
      break;
  }
}
```

In Drupal 7, the documentation for `hook_user_load()` states the following:

> Due to the static cache in `user_load_multiple()` you should not use this hook to modify the user properties returned by the {users} table itself since this may result in unreliable results when loading from cache.

Why do I get users and not just a user?

Is it ok to add properties to this?

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_load/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an array of user objects because the hook is called from [`user_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_load_multiple/7), which generally calls [`DrupalDefaultEntityController::load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController::load/7), which then calls [`DrupalDefaultEntityController::attachLoad()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController::attachLoad/7).

It is fine to add custom properties, but not to override the default properties that are loaded from the *{users}* table; as reported from the documentation, in that case you could get some problem when loading the user object from the cache, which is what the entity API normally does.

Comment: What if your external database contains a more authoritative email address for each user than what Drupal has? Is it still not okay to overwrite the Drupal value?

Comment: What I reported is valid also for `$user->mail`. If you have an external database that contains email addresses, you should import them into the database table used by Drupal. Drupal assumes its database is authoritative about its user's data.

Comment: OK, so is there a standard way to copy values over in a module? The information in the external login system may change at any time without Drupal knowing.